# Map Loop through ID and Object Values

Tags: apex, map

How do you loop through the Key and Values of the below properly?

```
Map<ID, Lead> mapLeads
```

I was able to loop through the keys but I am not sure how to loop through each keys values properly.

Comment: If you loop over keys, you can easily get values with `.get()`. Your map is 1:1 so values don't have elements. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the **Lead record or field values** using `key` inside your `for` loop then you can directly get the value from key inside the for loop by using `map.get(key)` (*this will return the Lead's record data based on the field you query in SOQL*) or `map.get(key).fieldName` (*this will return particular Lead's field value if you have queried the field in SOQL*).

Below is the code example:

```
for(Id key : mapLeads.ketSet()){
    System.debug('Lead Id: '+mapLeads.get(Key)); //print the Lead's record data.
    System.debug('Lead Id: '+mapLeads.get(Key).Id); //print the Lead id
    System.debug('Lead customField: '+mapLeads.get(Key).customFiled__c); //Print the Lead's custom Field value
}
```